# Artemis STOMP messages not delivered to OPENWIRE JMS clients

Tags: jms, stomp, activemq-artemis

We're trying to upgrade from ActiveMQ 5.x to the latest Artemis (2.17), but one of our applications is causing us grief.

The application is an older PHP web app that uses STOMP. It creates a temporary response queue, sends a message to the target, and then waits for a response. Under ActiveMQ 5.x, this works fine (and has for years), but with Artemis, the requests just hang until timeout.

The destination is a Java app based on the JMS API and Openwire. Most of our apps are like this and have no trouble communicating with each other...it's only this one PHP web app that's problematic, and it seems to be the only thing we have based on STOMP.

We ran a single transaction in isolation and with Artemis STOMP debugging enabled, here's what we see:

```
07:47:42,180 STOMP(/10.0.0.5:40618, f985f04d): IN << StompFrame[command=CONNECT, headers={login=<appid>, passcode=<app-password>}]
07:47:42,196 STOMP(/10.0.0.5:40618, f985f04d):OUT >> StompFrame[command=CONNECTED, headers={session=f985f04d}]
07:47:42,203 STOMP(/10.0.0.5:40618, f985f04d): IN << StompFrame[command=SUBSCRIBE, headers={ack=client, destination=/temp-queue/Reply-604379ee2f900, activemq.prefetchSize=1}]
07:47:42,235 STOMP(/10.0.0.5:40618, f985f04d): IN << StompFrame[command=SEND, headers={expires=1615035162000, destination=/queue/target, content-type=text/plain, reply-to=/temp-queue/Reply-604379ee2f900}, body=<--- message text---> body-bytes=[<--- message bytes --->, size=0]
07:48:42,247 STOMP(/10.0.0.5:40618, f985f04d): IN << StompFrame[command=DISCONNECT, headers={}]
```

The core of the problem seems to be that the message from the "SEND" operation shown above never gets to the receiver. We've verified that the receiver is online, and it responds to other clients connecting using JMS and Openwire connections - but this STOMP message isn't getting routed to the destination.

If we shutdown Artemis and revert back to ActiveMQ 5.x, the application works fine.

We are using the default  configuration:

```
<acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
         <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->
         <!-- amqpMinLargeMessageSize: Determines how many bytes are considered large, so we start using files to hold their data.
                                       default: 102400, -1 would mean to disable large mesasge control -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->


         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>
```

Is there some magic configuration we need that would route these STOMP messages to the proper destination?

Comment: Edited my question to include our acceptor configuration.

Comment: @Justin: I appreciate the update, but due to internal scheduling we're not able to test the problem app for another month or two. I'll definitely post another update when we get the chance to test again, and certainly if the bug report you created gets resolved, we'll give the updates a try too.

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is the `destination` to which the message is being sent. As described in [the ActiveMQ 5.x STOMP documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp) the `/queue/` prefix used on the `SEND` frame's `destination` header is automatically stripped. However, in ActiveMQ Artemis this needs to be configured explicitly via the `anycastPrefix` parameter discussed in the [ActiveMQ Artemis STOMP documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#configuring-routing-semantics-from-the-broker-side), e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;anycastPrefix=/queue/;multicastPrefix=/topic/</acceptor>
```

The `multicastPrefix` is also configured here for completeness.

Once that is configured then your message will be sent to `target` as expected.

However, I think there will still be an issue with the `/temp-queue/` prefix used on the `SUBSCRIBE` frame's `destination` header as well as the `reply-to` header on the `SEND` frame. ActiveMQ 5.x also treats these specially (although I can find no documentation about it). ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't create temporary resources for these, but I think you can still get the behavior your want because the broker can auto-create and auto-delete resources much as if they are temporary. The main thing you need to configure here are the prefixes like before, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;anycastPrefix=/queue/,/temp-queue/;multicastPrefix=/topic/,/temp-topic/</acceptor>
```

Since your Stomp clients are specifying the `reply-to` header using `/temp-queue/` and your OpenWire client is using this then you need to change your OpenWire `acceptor` as well, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;anycastPrefix=/temp-queue/;multicastPrefix=/temp-topic/</acceptor>
```

I've opened [ARTEMIS-3164](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3164) to implement a prefix for identifying temporary resources in ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: We had a chance to test the recommended changes overnight, and I'm sorry to say the results were mixed. The good news is that with the updated configuration you posted, messages do travel from the STOMP application to the OPENWIRE application properly. The responses, however, are not getting back to the STOMP client over its temporary queue. In the console, we can see the response queue (prefixed by "/temp-queue") and if I browse these queues, they seem to have the correct data - except is there no consumer created for these queues when the STOMP application subscribes for its response.

Comment: ...one other thing from our testing is that the trace of the STOMP activity is exactly the same as what I posted previously...

Comment: ...one other small hint: the OPENWIRE consumer processing these messages calls "getJMSReplyTo()", to get the reply queue name. When it sends a message to this ReplyTo address, it's getting a "DestinationDoesNotExistException".  This same flow works fine in ActiveMQ 5.x, and it also works with Artemis when the client is using OPENWIRE. This seems a little odd because I can see the pending response messages in the console, though there are no consumers for them.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comments. I'm not sure about the `DestinationDoesNotExistException` at this point. Do you have address and queue auto-creation enabled?